# Multiple models save in a POST request. (Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list.)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two models. Preference and CustomerPreference. I want to save multiple customer_preferences at a time. Now I am getting the following errror.

```
{
  "customer_preferences": {
    "non_field_errors": [
      "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."
    ]
  }
}
```

models.py

```
class Preferences(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class CustomerPreferences(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    preference = models.ForeignKey(Preferences, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='customer_preferences')
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, db_index=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                 related_name='customer_customer_preferences', null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='customer_preference_creator')
```

views.py

```
class PreferencesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PreferencesSerializer
    queryset = Preferences.objects.all()


class CustomerPreferenceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CustomerPreferencesSerializer
    queryset = CustomerPreferences.objects.all()

    model = CustomerPreferences

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = CustomerPreferences.objects.all()
        customer_id = self.request.query_params.get('customer_id', None)
        if customer_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(customer=customer_id)
        return queryset

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list' or self.action == 'retrieve':
            return CustomerPreferencesListSerializer
        return CustomerPreferenceSaveSerializer
```

serialzers.py

```
class PreferencesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = Preferences

    class Meta:
        model = Preferences
        fields = '__all__'


class CustomerPreferencesListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = CustomerPreferences
    preference = PreferencesSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerPreferences
        exclude = ('id','user',)


class CustomerPreferencesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = CustomerPreferences
    user = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerPreferences
        fields = '__all__'


class CustomerPreferenceSaveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer_preferences = CustomerPreferencesSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Preferences
        fields = ( 'customer_preferences',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        customer_preferences_data = validated_data.pop('customer_preferences')
        customer_id = request.POST.get('customer', None)

        for cust_prefernce in customer_preferences_data:
            cust_prefernce_obj = CustomerPreferences.objects.create(
                preference_id=cust_prefernce['preference'],
                status=cust_prefernce['status'],
                customer = customer_id,
                user = request.user
            )
        return CustomerPreferences.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
router.register(r'customer-preference', views.CustomerPreferenceViewSet, 'customers')
router.register(r'preference', views.PreferencesViewSet, 'preferences')
```

I want to submit the multiple customer_preferences as follows. Aslo 'customer' is not accessible from my serializers

POST request

```
{
  "customer":"ddf30356-9dba-4e0b-9ae7-9c589dff004",
  "customer_preferences":  [
    {
      "id": "20d1a84a-bde8-45dd-81bc-ce2fda855a91",
      "status": "like"
    },
    {
      "id": "df791115-dd5b-4446-b954-24f7c1bbc4f4",
      "status": "dislike"
    },
    {
      "id": "4a3c317f-f202-4b6f-ae9d-598c7aff5fe7",
      "status": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "9ac24dda-df86-4f11-a18d-6f438929751d",
      "status": "neutral"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you use DRF (Django Restframework) then you should not put the code for creating objects via post into your view. Instead the serializer does that or - if it is some custom object relation like yours - you override the methods of the serializer that do the saving.

Comment: I just had to add `many=True` in `customer_preferences = CustomerPreferencesSerializer(many=True)` and the other similar lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resolved the issues by updating the serializer as follows.

serializers.py

```
class CustomerPreferencesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = CustomerPreferences
    user = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerPreferences
        fields = '__all__'


class CustomerPreferencesListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = Preferences
    customer_preferences = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_customer_preferences(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        customer_id = request.query_params.get('customer_id', None)
        customer_pref = CustomerPreferences.objects.filter(preference_id=obj, customer=customer_id)
        serializer = CustomerPreferencesSerializer(customer_pref, many=True)
        return serializer.data



    class Meta:
        model = Preferences
        fields = ('id', 'title','status')


class CustomerPreferenceSaveSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    model = Customer
    customer_preferences = CustomerPreferencesSerializer(source='customer_customer_preferences', many=True,read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('customer','customer_preferences',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        customer = request.data.get('customer', None)
        customer_preferences_data = request.data.get('customer_preferences', [])

        # first delete all entries of the given customer
        customer_preferences_obj = CustomerPreferences.objects.filter(customer=customer)
        customer_preferences_obj.delete()

        for cust_prefernce in customer_preferences_data:
            cust_prefernce_obj = CustomerPreferences.objects.create(
                preference_id=cust_prefernce['preference'],
                status=cust_prefernce['status'],
                customer_id = customer,
                user = request.user
            )

        return Customer.objects.all().get(id=customer)
```

views.py

```
class PreferencesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = PreferencesSerializer
queryset = Preferences.objects.all()


class CustomerPreferenceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CustomerPreferencesSerializer
    queryset = CustomerPreferences.objects.all()

    model = CustomerPreferences

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Preferences.objects.all()
        return queryset

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list' or self.action == 'retrieve':
            return CustomerPreferencesListSerializer
        return CustomerPreferenceSaveSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

You have posted the model `CustomerPreferences` which defines a mapping between a customer and a preference.

The serializer you posted is the one for this mapping - it serializes the relation between one preference and one customer.

I think you want to display/update the preferences of one customer so my answer is based on that assumption.

With your current model structure you get the CustomerPreferences of one customer with `customer.customer_customer_preferences.all()`. You need a CustomerSerializer that uses the CustomerPreferencesSerializer(many=True) to handle multiple preferences:

```
class CustomerSerializer(Serializer):
     model = Customer
     # ... more fields
     customer_preferences = CustomerPreferencesSerializer(source='customer_customer_preferences', many=True)
```

Code is not tested. You will probably need custom code for saving.

See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Comment: The fix obviously worked because now the code runs further and you get a different error. SO is not about fixing your whole code - it's about solving a certain problem to help everyone else in the future who happens to have a similar problem.